# Should I make my dataclass hashable to use it in a set or leave it unhashable, use it in a list and check for duplicates?

Tags: python, hash, python-dataclasses

Every once in a while I face this dilemma and don't know what to do. Recently I have been working on an program where I am using sqlalchemy and making the class `frozen=True` don't work well with it. The solution is to make `unsafe_hash=True` (which obviously makes a beginner like me frightened in some situations). I fell like I should always use `eq=True` instead of `unsafe_hash=True`, but on the other hand, having a set would remove a lot of loops and conditional logic from my code.

For a more practical example, this post has an implementation that makes me in doubt if it is a good solution, since it require the need to enforce that `name` and `dob` never change ([Python dataclass generate hash and exclude unsafe fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61740748/python-dataclass-generate-hash-and-exclude-unsafe-fields)). In my case I would do that to use a `person` in a `set()`. Also, I might want to change the value of `name` for some random reason.

What is the ideal solution? Does it make any sense to have some kind of randomly generated attribute for such a class (using uuid maybe) and use it in the `__hash__`? And how would I enforce that the hash would never change?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! Questions that ask for general guidance regarding a problem approach are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a correct answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), and  [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") then edit your post.

Comment: The concept of an "unsafe" hash should always frighten, beginners and those familiar with Python alike :-)